# Why slicing in boolean filtered array is not happening..?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

When I try to slice the boolean filtered numpy array it's not **changing** its value.
please look a

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
array[array>=2]
```

array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
array[array>=2][1:5]
```

array([3, 4, 5, 6])

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
array[array>=2][1:5] = [1,1,1,1]
array
```

array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

When I changed [1:5] index into ones it's not changing it's vale...How can I change these value in boolean filter.?

Comment: Once you use a boolean index, you are working with a new array containing these elements, rather than the original array. You need to save the new array as variable, otherwise you will write new values, but have no way to access the afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [246]: arr = np.arange(1,9)
In [247]: mask = arr>=2
In [248]: mask
Out[248]: array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

`arr[mask]` makes a new array, a copy (not a view).  You can slide and modify it, but it won't affect `arr`.

Instead you have to modify the `mask` or an indexed derived from it.

One way:

```
In [249]: idx = np.nonzero(mask)[0]
In [250]: idx
Out[250]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
In [251]: arr[idx[1:5]]
Out[251]: array([3, 4, 5, 6])
In [252]: arr[idx[1:5]] = 1
In [253]: arr
Out[253]: array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8])
```

[252] has just one indexing operation, so the assignment works.

I could go into how `array[array>=2][1:5] = [1,1,1,1]` evaluates as separate get and set operations if needed.